# How can I format the axes in plotRGB from the R raster package?

Tags: r, plot, rgb, raster

I'm trying to plot two plots side by side. One is a RasterStack for which I'm using plotRGB(). The axes are a mess however - it is plotting too many decimal places for the latitude and longitude. I'd also like to change the font size and text orientation.

This is straightforward in plot(), but I can't figure it out for plotRGB.

Can anyone help?

This is the code:

```
par(mar=c(4,5,4,2), mfrow = c(1, 2))
plotRGB(tayRGB, axes = TRUE, stretch = "lin", main = "RGB")
plot(knr, main = "Kmeans", cex.axis=0.96, col = viridis_pal(option="D")(10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can I recommend to use the function `RStoolbox)::ggRGB` instead of plotRGB.  This will give you the full functionality of ggplot to customise your plot. A reproducible example:

```
set.seed(123)
R = raster(matrix(runif(400),20,20))
G = raster(matrix(runif(400),20,20))
B = raster(matrix(runif(400),20,20))
tayRGB = brick(list(R,G,B))

library(RStoolbox)
p1 = ggRGB(tayRGB, r=1, g=2, b=3, stretch = 'lin') +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.001)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = scales::number_format(accuracy = 0.1)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 30),
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 45))
p1
```

[image]

To plot your other plot side by side with this, you can either remake it as a ggplot.  Or you can use ggplotify::base2grob to convert a base R plot into a grob.

```
p2 = ggplotify::base2grob(~plot(rnorm(100)))
cowplot::plot_grid(p1,p2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @dww. ggRGB does look good. It is plotting and giving control over the text options, which is great, but there are a few side effects...

The image seems to be stretched (width is twice the height), and there's an error thrown relating to the number_format:

```{r}
Error: 'number_format' is not an exported object from 'namespace:scales'
```
If this is removed. it works ok, but with the stretching noted above. Thanks again for your really speedy reply!

Comment: You did not provide a reproducible example (something that is normally expected for this type of question), so I have no way to know why you have a 2:1 aspect ratio. The most likely reason is that the geographic extent of your raster is in fact this shape.  The aspect ratio can of course be altered to anything you want using coord_fixed(), but it is more likely that the raster is already the correct shape.  As to `scales::number_format` try reinstalling the package scales.  If you have it correctly installed then this is indeed an exported function.